# Why does string.insert(iterator,char) work six times in a row but not seven? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, insert, iterator, segmentation-fault

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string expand(string mask);

int main()
{
    string tiny = "blah blah [a-e] blah blah";
    string lengthy = "blah blah [a-i] blah blah";
    cout << expand(tiny) << endl;
    cout << expand(lengthy) << endl;
    return 0;
}


string expand(string mask)
{
    int i, range;

    /* find the first bracket, grab start letter */
    unsigned int bracket = mask.find("[");
    char start = mask[bracket + 1];

    /* point iterator at first bracket */
    string::iterator here = mask.begin();
    here += bracket;

    /* find second bracket, calculate ascii range */
    range = mask[bracket + 3] - mask[bracket + 1];

    /* kill brackets and their contents*/
    mask.erase(here, here + 5);

    /*** This loop causes an error on the 7th iteration ****/
    for(i = 0; i <= range; i++)
        mask.insert(here, (start + range) - i);

    return mask;
}
```

**Output:**

> matt@Callandor:~/prog/tempVer$ g++
>   test.cpp -o play
>
> matt@Callandor:~/prog/tempVer$ ./play
>
> blah blah abcde blah blah
>
> ���blah blah defghi blah blah
>
> *** glibc detected *** ./play: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08353068
>
> ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c501)[0x5b5501]...

I am running into some odd behavior when trying to use string::insert(iterator,char);  I have it inside a 'for' loop where I don't move the iterator at all, the loop just inserts characters.  It works fine if I have six or fewer characters to insert, but fails for seven or more.

Based on the output (see above) it looks like after six insertions the iterator jumps to the beginning of the string and begins inserting garbage.  When the program finishes I get a large messy error.

While trying to isolate the cause I tried two loops (none of which touch the iterator):

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    mask.insert(here, (start + range) - i);
    cout << mask << endl;

for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    mask.insert(here, (start + range) - i);
    cout << mask << endl;
```

The first completed just fine, the second caused a segmentation fault.

Anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: The indentation of your last example is quite misleading.

Answer (score 9):

After pouring over your code, I noticed that you are using an invalidated iterator.

In a nutshell, insertion into a string invalidates its iterators. After your insert, the `here` iterator is no longer valid, because, among other implementation specific details, the string capacity could have increased. This leads to undefined behavior when the `here` iterator is used again after the insert, without first being reset to a valid spot in the modified string.

Comment: Brilliant!  I was wondering why string::insert returned an iterator, now it makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Probably because when the string has to resize, the internal string will be at a different location in memory and your iterator, `here`, becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1):

`std::basic_string<T>::insert` invalidates ALL iterators. Therefore `here` is not valid after the `insert` call. Therefore the program has undefined behavior and is allowed to format your hard disk if it want's to :)

Seriously though, you want `here = mask.insert(here, (start + range) - i);` as the body of that for loop.

Oh, and you should probably make sure the `find` operation succeeds before proceeding :)

**EDIT**: You're probably better off refactoring this into something which builds a string containing what you want to add, then running a single `insert`, rather than running `n` inserts, because `n` inserts results in an algorithm with potentially quadratic time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I'm qualified to give you advice here, but it sure smells like you're indexing past the end of the array.

Comment: I don't see indexes being used at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

The questioner asked why it worked for 6 and not for 7.

The other posters have come close by answering the second part, so I will clarify that insert **may** invalidate your iterators, but will not necessarily.

If insert has to reallocate memory then it will invalidate iterators. If it does not have to reallocate memory the iterators might not become invalidated.

You were therefore "lucky" the first 6 times but finally got caught.

You are also erasing 5 elements so that might invalidate your iterators, however in this case your iterator is probably just implemented as a pointer or a light wrapper to one, so again you "got away with it".

You should not normally rely on getting away with it, but in the case you first call reserve() and then you just do push_back() calls, you can be certain your iterators will not be invalidated until you pass the capacity you have reserved.